# Set audioUnit, or just another class to not being on the main thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio

I have a main view (or a scene in cocos2d) that opens when the app is starts .
from there i call the audioUnit to listen to the input audio that comes from microphone .
it works great (the callbacks on audioUnit are called always and do stuff) , but i can see that it takes the main thread- something that i dont want because the main scene has `UILabel` and other stuff that needs to be the main thread in order to be changed .

at the `main scene` i do at the start  :

```
remoteIns=[[remoteIO alloc]init]; //turn on the callback function on class remoteIO .
[remoteIns StartListeningWithFrequency]; // this function takes the main thread
```

then when i check in the `main scene` later with :

```
NSLog(@"isMainThread%d",[NSThread isMainThread]);
```

i can see it's not the main thread ,hence i cant change `UILabels` in it .

I need to start the audioUnit function (another class) and set it to be in another thread, keep the main scene to be the main thread, and let the `audioUnit` work good .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio Unit is not in the main thread.
But the main scene is also not in the main thread.

In order to change the UILabel on the main scene , it most be the main thread, so i change its text with this : (its being called in the scene observer to call a function that changes the text :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( updateText: ) withObject: bits waitUntilDone: YES];
```

and in `updateText:` i change the text. it works great .

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to run something on the main thread is to use a block.  This way, you can perform more than one operation, and it looks like "normal" code.  It is also **much** simpler to call routines that take more than two arguments:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Any code that you put in here will be run on the main thread.
    // However, MAKE SURE that you do not actually call this from the main thread or
    // your program will hang!

    // i.e.:
    self.label.text = @"New text";       
});
```